# Impression Region name in ContentArea() function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

In `ContentArea(1,2,3,4,5)` AMPScript function the 2nd parameter is "Name of Impression Region".

What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Impression Region" is used to track links that contain AMPScript in them. By assigning a value here, you are giving a name for the links that will appear in the click activity report under tracking.

More info: [**Impression Tracking**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/tracking/impression_tracking/)